# How do you set a label text as something from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, label

I am trying to understand how to set a label to be the text from an array when you press the button. When I press the button, the label disappears, and then nothing comes up. No crashes in code.

Relevant code:

```
-(void)setupArray {

    wordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [wordArray addObject:@"test1"];
    [wordArray addObject:@"test2"];
    [wordArray addObject:@"test3"];
}

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

    int value = (arc4random() % 3) + 1;

    self.typeThis.text = [self.wordArray objectAtIndex:value];

}
```

typeThis is the label name, and I think I have hooked up everything already, i.e. set up the buttons/delegates/etc...I don't understand why it isn't working. Can anybody help?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your IBAction method and check that it's being hit. Continue to step through it and see that value is populated and then whether it extracts anything from your array.

Comment: @Huddy BUddy - Based on the answers that I've seen so far, I believe you should let us know if you are using ARC.  The easiest way to tell is this: Are you manually doing "Retain" and/or "Releases" on your objects?  If you are, then you are NOT using ARC.  ARC stands for Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: I am using ARC, since I am not using the release/retain stuff

Answer (score 2):

considering you have bound everything properly and you are not under ARC. Here is a thing that might cause you the issue.
when you are `alloc`ating `wordArray` you can try using following code snippet.

```
NSMutableArray tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.wordArray = tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

if you are under ARC you can try `self.wordArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

then add objects to `self.wordArray` i.e.`[self.wordArray addObject:@"test1"];`. Here is [some explanation](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) about `arc4random()`.

**EDIT :** 
Here's a public spec for [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) and a [quote from the public iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/) page:

> Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) for Objective-C makes memory
>   management the job of the compiler. By enabling ARC with the new Apple
>   LLVM compiler, you will never need to type retain or release again,
>   dramatically simplifying the development process, while reducing
>   crashes and memory leaks. The compiler has a complete understanding of
>   your objects, and releases each object the instant it is no longer
>   used, so apps run as fast as ever, with predictable, smooth
>   performance.

It is possible to detect if ARC is enabled. Simply add the following snippet to any file that requires ARC.

```
#ifndef __has_feature
  #define __has_feature(x) 0 /* for non-clang compilers */
#endif

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
  #error ARC must be enabled!
#endif
```

More info :
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#__has_feature_extension

HTH.

Comment: What is ARC and how do you check if you are under ARC?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your '+1' is giving you a result between 1 and 3, and your indexes are from 0 to 2, so I'd expect it to go wrong one time in 3.

Comment: i have changed that and it still doesn't work, also, the value is being calculated fine

Answer (score 0):

Is this under ARC?  If so, is wordArray declare as strong?

Comment: I don't know what ARC is, how do you check? Also, yes, I declared as strong, should I do weak?

Comment: If you're doing retain/releases yourself, then you're not using ARC. If you've elected to use ARC, it will add them for you. See http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/

Comment: not using ARC then, because I don't do the release statements etc.